# Выполнение alias'ов шела средствами Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, shell

Работаю с модулем subprocess. При выполнении кода по типу:

```
subprocess.call('ls')
```

в консоль получаем ожидаемый вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

задача была в том, чтобы также вызвать alias команды, например

```
subprocess.call('la')
```

который эвивалентен записи ls -A, но при таком раскладе интерпритатор выдаёт ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В скрипте мне нужно вызывать именно alias'ы команд. Возможно ли это сделать средствами python? Или проще создать словарь со значениями alias'ов и команд, но тогда как передавать в subprocess аргументы, если я не знаю сколько дополнительных параметров будет у той или иной комманды (а это может быть и довольно громоздкий из нескольких строк сценарий)? Ай нид хэлп)

Comment: ls -a суть лишь пример. А если у нас комманда с кучей параметров на несколько строк с перенаправлением вывода и прочими плюшками, как её запихнуть в subprocess?

Comment: Попробуйте инициализировать алиасы так `subprocess.call('source ~/.bashrc; la')` если конечно для алиасов не выбран другой файл

Comment: P.S. изначально имеем прочитаный файл конфига .bashrc (.bash/zsh_aliases), записаный в упорядочекнный словарь OrderedDict

Comment: насколько я понимаю, каждый раз при вызове создается отдельная сессия и в каждой нужно вначале инициализировать файл с алиасами

Comment: вероятно вы правы, попробую потом отпишусь

Comment: subprocess.call почему-то откказывается выполнять source FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'source'

Comment: но ваш ход мыслей верный, буду продолжать копать

Comment: Можно попробовать вместо `source` использовать `.`

Comment: походу дела . и source это тоже своего рода алиасы. Впрочем на which source консолька отвечает source: shell built-in command. В общем средствами пайтон мне так и не удалось их обуздать. Зато если создать sh скрипт с кодом source ~/.zshrc, например, а дальше указать алиас, из запустить его через subprocess.Popen(['zsh', '/home/cre8/playground/test/test.sh']), то всё работает и алиас выполняется. Остается только передать нужный параметр в test.sh из сценария пайтон)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например, так:

```
$ python -c 'import subprocess,os; subprocess.call([os.environ["SHELL"],"-ic","la"])'
```

опции поддерживаются [всеми posix-совместимыми оболочками](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html):

- `-i` — интерактивная сессия
- `-c команда` — выполнить команду

Comment: спасибо, помогло)